# MySQL information_schema report less rows than count()

Tags: mysql

Figures reported by `MySQL` `count(*)` and on `information_schema.TABLES` are totally different.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: def
   TABLE_SCHEMA: my_db
     TABLE_NAME: my_table
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: InnoDB
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Compact
     TABLE_ROWS: 31016698
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 399
    DATA_LENGTH: 12378439680
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 0
   INDEX_LENGTH: 4863262720
      DATA_FREE: 5242880
 AUTO_INCREMENT: NULL
    CREATE_TIME: 2016-06-14 18:54:24
    UPDATE_TIME: NULL
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8_general_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS: 
  TABLE_COMMENT: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> select count(*) from my_table;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 46406095 |
+----------+
1 row in set (27.45 sec)
```

Note that there are *31,016,698* rows according to `information_schema`, `count()` however report *46,406,095* rows...

Now which one can be trusted? Why these stats are different?

I'm using *MySQL server v5.6.30*.

Answer (score 2):

The count in that metadata, similar to the output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, cannot be trusted. It's often off by a factor of 100 or more, either over or under.

The reason for this is the engine does not know how many rows are in the table until it calculates this. Under heavy load you might have a lot of contention on the primary key index which makes pinning down an exact value an expensive computation.

This approximation is computed based on the total data length divided by the average row length. It's rarely even close to what it should be unless your records are all about the same length and you haven't been deleting a lot of them.

The only value that can be truly trusted is `COUNT(*)` but that operation can take a long time to complete, so be warned.